# TensorFlow Example vs SequenceExample

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tfrecord

Theres not that much information given in the TensorFlow documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SequenceExample

It just refers you to:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto

There is a short description of each as well as an example; however, I still don’t have a solid understanding as to why you would choose one over the other? Can someone please help explain?